# How to do corners of shed siding using fence pickets

Tags: framing, siding, shed

I am planning to use existing fence pickets to build a shed and use them for siding. But I can't figure out (or come to conclusion) on how to deal with the 4 corners. I highlighted red in below

[image]

That one looks like it's just a 2x4. So how can the fence pickets not end up to be ON TOP / OUTSIDE of the 2x4 framing?

I looked at this video online and they installed a corner board: https://youtu.be/Z00berTW5hc?t=43m8s

[image]

So I assume it's something like this "Outside Corner Moulding", right?

http://www.homedepot.com/p/Royal-Mouldings-6577-11-16-in-x-11-16in-x-8-ft-PVC-Composite-White-Outside-Corner-Moulding-0657708011/100074043

I am trying to save money and not buy additional corner board if possible. So how do I do this with existing 2x4 framing or fence pickets? That'd be great.

Comment: They are on top of the framing (sheathing and wrap, if used). What's the confusion?

Comment: The picture looks like it's one piece. So is it a one-inch thick material? Am I right that it's called "corner board"?

Comment: I've never seen such a thing other than for vinyl or steel siding. I've always made my own.

Comment: I would like to make mine own also. Would it be just a 1" - 1.5" cedar? Because I have some cedar decking board left over.

Comment: Size depends on the depth of the siding and your personal style preferences. There are no standards. Just be sure you have enough edge face to caulk to, should that be necessary. You can build them out with furring strips if needed.

Answer (score 2):

The corner is made out of two corner boards. They overlap like this looking down from the top:

[image]

Depending upon how you want the corner to actually look the corner boards may be made from planed cedar boards instead of fence pickets which are typically rough with a sawn surface.

Comment: The corner board doesn't nail on top of the siding right? It's on top of the studs? Since basically my siding would be overlapping fence pickets so they are not "flat" at the edges.

Comment: Yeah, corners are rarely *over* the siding. The exception would be flat plywood siding, but that's way out of fashion in my part of the world.

Comment: Actually corner boards are implemented many ways. When they do not go on top of the siding then then there is generally a sheathing over the studs to which the siding and corner boards are mounted. In that case the siding is butted up to the edge of the corner board. However in the case where the siding and sheathing are one and the same then it is much more likely that the corner boards go over the siding because if the corner boards went right on the studs there is not much coverage of the siding to the studs and this is a decided disadvantage. First there is smaller space (continued)

Comment: (continued from above) to nail the ends of the siding and the siding thus provides a lot less strength to keeping the building square and true.